# Selecting from xml specifying an order

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

using xslt 1.0 on python, I am trying to select a few items while specifying order:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item name='1'>
first
</item>
<item name='2'>
second
</item>
<item name='3'>
third
</item>
</items>
```

If I use a for-each with a big OR'd together list, I can get the items I want, but only in the original order of the xml source document above.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item[@name='2']|items/item[@name='1']">
<p>hi</p>
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces:

```
hi
first
hi
second
```

But I would like to have it output:

```
hi
second
hi
first
```

I think using xsl:apply-templates might be the way to go, but I can't get it to work with even this simple example.  What is the best way in xslt 1.0 to select elements in a specific order?

Comment: See the answer that har07 gave you (with the two `apply-templates`), the union operator `|` you use sorts its operands in document order so your attempt with `select="items/item[@name='2']|items/item[@name='1']"` does not define an order for the `for-each`, as you want to. In XSLT 2.0 you could use the comma operator `,`, as in `select="items/item[@name='2'],items/item[@name='1']"`, but XSLT 1.0 does not have that operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<xsl:sort>` to specify ordering especially when there is a *specific logic to define the ordering*, for example to order by `name` attribute value in descending order :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html> 
      <body> 
        <xsl:for-each select="items/item[@name='2' or @name='1']"> 
          <xsl:sort select="@name" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
          <p>hi</p>  
          <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
      </body> 
    </html> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform demo 1`](http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWi/1)</kbd>**

> *"I think using xsl:apply-templates might be the way to go, but I can't get it to work with even this simple example"*

That's also possible, for example :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <html> 
      <body> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item[@name='2']"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="items/item[@name='1']"/>
      </body> 
    </html> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="items/item">
      <p>hi</p>  
      <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**<kbd>[`xsltransform demo 2`](http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38Zk)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>hi</p>
      second

      <p>hi</p>
      first

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the xsl:apply-templates is the best solution for me (the sort is not because the order is arbitrary).  Most of the issues for me were typo and node-set related. The links to xmltransform.net were fantastic.  Much better than the other online xslt tool I was using.